# Coexistence between Azure P2S VPN and Expressroute

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

On microsoft azure i have a point to site VPN. The adress pool is  192.168.54.0/24.

I also have an azure virtual network and the adress space is 192.168.53.0/24. This virtual network is connected to my on-premise site by an expressroute (My on premise site  network adress is 192.168.55.0)

When a user is connected to my P2S VPN, he can contact(ping, RDS,etc...) Virtual machine in the 192.168.53.0 network but can't contact the on-premise servers(192.168.55.0).

[image]

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: I'm not sure this setup will work at all, but you can try creating a route on your laptop to access 192.168.55.0/24 through the VPN gateway internal IP address

Comment: @4c74356b41, thanks for your answer. I've made a tracert from the laptop on 192.168.55.5, here is the line:
 1    44 ms    42 ms    44 ms  192.168.54.1
So, i suppose the route exists. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation and microsoft azure assistance, this kind of communication is not supported.

### https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-howto-coexist-resource-manager#limits-and-limitations

"Transit routing is not supported. You cannot route (via Azure) between your local network connected via Site-to-Site VPN and your local network connected via ExpressRoute."

Answer (score 0):

We do know that transit routing is possible when using P2S VPN and trying to connect to on-prem via a S2S VPN in some scenarios (if this S2S VPN is using BGP routing, and if routes on the client are manually added, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-point-to-site-routing). But this does not mention ExpressRoute.

As posted in Aldwen's answer,  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-howto-coexist-resource-manager#limits-and-limitations) MS do state that Transit routing is not supported for ExpressRoute, but it only mentions for the connection via a Site-to-Site VPN - unfortunately this does not definitively state that Transit routing is not possible when using P2S VPN.

However, Microsoft Azure Virtual WAN solution (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-wan/virtual-wan-about), does support multiple different transitive routing scenarios - "These functionalities include Branch connectivity.., Site-to-site VPN connectivity, Remote User VPN (Point-to-site) connectivity, Private (ExpressRoute) connectivity, Intra cloud connectivity (Transitive connectivity for Virtual Networks), VPN ExpressRoute Interconnectivity, Routing, Azure firewall, Encryption for private connectivity etc."
So my reading here is that Azure Virtual Wan will support all these transitive routing scenario's to allow the transitive routing for P2S and S2S and ExpressRoute, and will indeed allow P2S VPN to access on-prem via ExpressRoute as per the OP's scenario.